# Virtual Web Cam

Tags: windows-7, windows, virtual-webcam

Are there any free virtual webcam softwares which will display my screen instead. I do have my own webcam but am looking for an alternative through which any software can access this virtual webcam which will display my screen instead of me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/index.aspx)** is a remote access / desktop sharing application, the new version 5 supports voice chat.

> TeamViewer allows you to present your
>   desktop to a partner. Share live
>   demos, products, and presentations
>   over the Internet within seconds.

Answer (score 3):

Last versions of [Skype](http://skype.com) can send your screen as a "webcam image" in video calls.

Comment: I'm looking for a virtual webcam software i already know of skype and its usage

Answer (score 1):

GoToMeeting or WebEx are good meeting hosting services with screen sharing.